# computed property 'name' was assigned but it has not setter (without v-model)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I'm trying to make a navigation Active when it is clicked on by adding the class `nav-selected`. I've seen other questions like this but they are related to `v-model` hence they didn't help me.

I need to make sure that it is added to the store so that I can always see what page is active even after a refresh. However I'm receiving the following error:

[image: error]

**Navigation.vue:**

```
    <template>
    <v-container>
        <v-layout align-center>
            <!-- Logo -->
            <v-flex sm2>
                <img src="http://beam.space/img/icon.png" height="30px">
            </v-flex>
            <!-- Navigation -->
            <v-flex sm8>
                <v-layout wrap justify-center>
                    <v-flex sm2>
                        <router-link to="/myspaces">
                            <h2 @click="setActiveNav(0)" :class="{'nav-selected': activeNavigation === 0}" class="nav-text">My Spaces</h2>
                        </router-link>

                    </v-flex>

                    <v-flex sm2>
                        <router-link to="/inspirations">
                            <h2 @click="setActiveNav(1)" :class="{'nav-selected': activeNavigation === 1}" class="nav-text">Inspirations</h2>
                        </router-link>
                    </v-flex>
                </v-layout>
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex sm2>
                <p>profile</p>
            </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
    import { mapState } from 'vuex';

    export default {
        name: "navigation",
        computed: {
            ...mapState([
                'activeNavigation'
            ])
        },
        methods: {
            setActiveNav(activeNav) {
                this.activeNavigation = activeNav;
                this.store.commit('setActiveNavigation', this.activeNavigation);
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

**Store.js:**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        activeNavigation: 0
    },
getters: {

    },
    mutations: {
        // Set Active navigation on click.
        setActiveNavigation(state, id) {
            state.activeNavigation = id;
        }

    },

    // actions zijn a sync
    actions: {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mapState` creates getter properties only. You cannot assign to those properties.

There is no need to assign to `activeNavigation` anyway, the commit will update the mapped value of `activeNavigation` automatically.

Change this:

```es6
setActiveNav(activeNav) {
    this.activeNavigation = activeNav;  // <-- Not allowed
    this.store.commit('setActiveNavigation', this.activeNavigation);
}
```

to this:

```es6
setActiveNav(activeNav) {
    this.$store.commit('setActiveNavigation', activeNav);
}
```

Comment: That makes sense! However now I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'commit' of undefined`. `activeNav` is not undefined, so what is?

Comment: `store` should be `$store`.

Comment: Perfect that works, however.. when I reload the page, it doesn't seem to memorise the activeNavigation. It reloads and the `activeNavigation` is reset. Am I confused on how the store is suppose to work?

Comment: The Vuex state does not persist across page reloads. There are [solutions](https://www.google.com/search?q=vuex+persist) to this, but it is a whole other question which I will not go into detail here.